# Icons not showing in SherlockPreferenceActivity on GingerBread (2.3)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-preferences, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have an app that uses ActionBarSherlock and I have a Preference screen that extend off of SherlockPreferenceActivity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends SherlockPreferenceActivity
```

My preference XML looks something like:

```
<Preference
    android:icon="@drawable/settings_prefs_call_settings"
    android:key="pref_btn_call_settings"
    android:summary="Change call settings"
    android:title="Call Settings" />

<Preference
    android:icon="@drawable/call_settings_prefs_my_phone_number"
    android:key="pref_btn_my_phone_number"
    android:summary="Change settings relating to your phone number"
    android:title="My Phone Number" />
```

When I run this on Android 2.3, the icons (`@drawable/call_settings_prefs_my_phone_number` and `@drawable/settings_prefs_call_settings`) never show on the preference screen but show up fine on ICS and JB.

Can anyone tell me how I can get the icons to show up on GB?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Looking at the Preference documentation the icon attribute was added in API level 1. However, when I try to set the icon programmatically with .setIcon(int), it says the method was introduced in API level 11. SO maybe the icon attribute was added in API level 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferences's icon is only supported by Api 11+.So is ActionBarSherlock.